# Python-docx: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, python-docx

I'm trying to get the text from Paragraphs.

But there is a paragraph contains two objects(lists).

How can I take the first list only?

```
print(doc.paragraphs[i].runs)
```

output(two lists):

```
[<docx.text.run.Run object at 0x000002A9AAD98E08>, <docx.text.run.Run object at 0x000002A9AAD98B88>, <docx.text.run.Run object at 0x000002A9AAD98648>, <docx.text.run.Run object at 0x000002A9AAD98088>, <docx.text.run.Run object at 0x000002A9AAD98548>, <docx.text.run.Run object at 0x000002A9AAD98A48>, <docx.text.run.Run object at 0x000002A9AAD98988>, <docx.text.run.Run object at 0x000002A9AAD98A88>, <docx.text.run.Run object at 0x000002A9AAD98048>, <docx.text.run.Run object at 0x000002A9AAD98708>, <docx.text.run.Run object at 0x000002A9AAD98BC8>, <docx.text.run.Run object at 0x000002A9AAD98188>, <docx.text.run.Run object at 0x000002A9AAD98B08>, <docx.text.run.Run object at 0x000002A9AAD98108>, <docx.text.run.Run object at 0x000002A9AAD986C8>, <docx.text.run.Run object at 0x000002A9AAD982C8>, <docx.text.run.Run object at 0x000002A9AAD981C8>, <docx.text.run.Run object at 0x000002A9AAD98948>, <docx.text.run.Run object at 0x000002A9AAD98288>, <docx.text.run.Run object at 0x000002A9AAD98248>, <docx.text.run.Run object at 0x000002A9AAD98808>, <docx.text.run.Run object at 0x000002A9AAD98208>, <docx.text.run.Run object at 0x000002A9AAD98DC8>, <docx.text.run.Run object at 0x000002A9AAD98608>, <docx.text.run.Run object at 0x000002A9AAD98688>, <docx.text.run.Run object at 0x000002A9AAD98148>, <docx.text.run.Run object at 0x000002A9AAD98C48>, <docx.text.run.Run object at 0x000002A9AAD98E48>, <docx.text.run.Run object at 0x000002A9AAD98A08>, <docx.text.run.Run object at 0x000002A9AAD98908>]
[<docx.text.run.Run object at 0x000002A9AADB4D88>, <docx.text.run.Run object at 0x000002A9AADB4CC8>, <docx.text.run.Run object at 0x000002A9AADB4BC8>, <docx.text.run.Run object at 0x000002A9AADB4D48>]
```

when use blow

```
print(doc.paragraphs[i].runs[0])
```

then comes the first item of both lists. I want one of this two lists.

```
<docx.text.run.Run object at 0x0000028F33B58E88>
<docx.text.run.Run object at 0x0000028F33B74C48>
```

when trying to use two value:

```
a,b = doc.paragraphs[i].runs
```

then got the error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

How can I do?

===Update===

I found my mistake in the code!
It's because my if-condition.
Thanks for answering my question.

Comment: what is "i" and where it is initialized? shed some light on how you got the input data. `doc.paragraphs[i].runs`

Comment: @dhamodaran i think the code is in a for loop

Comment: Yes, it's what @PyGamer0 said !

Comment: @AsterLin show the minimal code it takes to reproduce this error, including the for loop(s). Don't ask us to guess what code you used to produce this result; that wastes our time. For example if I try to run `print(doc.paragraphs[i].runs)` I get `NameError: name 'doc' is not defined`.

Answer (score 2):

```
a,b,*_ = doc.paragraphs[i].runs
```

a and b gets the first 2 *lists*, _ gets the rest.

Edit: here's how to get the first *list*

```
a, *_ = doc.paragraphs[i].runs
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering.
But I want to get the first list, not the first 2 values of two lists.

Comment: Hi, It's the same. Now the situation is like  A= [1,2] [3,4], and if I take A[0], then the result comes 1,3. However, what I want is [1,2].

Comment: @AsterLin how is that possible? A = [[1,2],[3,4]], A[0] should return [1,2]?! Or is it a different structure?

Comment: I also don't know why ?? Perhaps, the structure is really different from any other? Hope someone can tell me why (sad)

Answer (score 0):

You can try ast if it helps

```
import ast
input = doc.paragraphs[i].runs
output = ast.literal_eval(input,ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8')
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering. However it comes error:
ValueError: malformed node or string: [<docx.text.run.Run object at 0x0000018ECB433EC8>]